# How do I run a .jar executable java file from outside NetBeans IDE?

Tags: java, executable-jar

How do I run a .jar executable java file from outside NetBeans IDE? (Windows Vista).  My project has a .jar file created by Netbeans.  We'd like to run it.  Either: how do we run the file or how do we create a 'proper' executable file in NetBeans 6.1?

Answer (score 18):

Running a jar is as simple as

```
java -jar filename.jar
```

Answer (score 4):

as Laplie said, java -jar your.jar

EXECUTABLE file : see this thread for answers [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

Answer (score 4):

One of the best technique to run the jar file or jar jar file

1. Create the jar file by jar command choose your jar filename
   `Java_Jar_File.jar`
2. Run the jar file us the command like `java -jar Java_Jar_File.jar`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it from the command prompt if java isn't in your path by finding the full path to your java install, something like:

```
C:\java\java.exe -jar C:\jar_you_want_to_run.jar
```

or if java is in your path:

```
java.exe -jar jar_you_want_to_run.jar
```

This will run the jar produced by netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you set the Main Class in your NetBeans project properties dialog.
Then, you can either

- Double-click the jar file (This should work on any machine with an installed JRE)

or

- Make sure that java.exe is in the path (or replace `java` below with the fullpath and file name of the executable), put the following in a batch file:
  `java -jar filename.jar`
  Then you can double-click the batch file instead of the jar (useful if you have people unaccustomed to using naked jar files)

OR

- You can go down the path described here [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file) to build a .exe for windows.

Answer (score 2):

Make a BAT file with

```
java -jar filepath.jar
```

Comment: I did't make a bat file, but i ran this command on terminal and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

from a command prompt you can run this command: `java -jar your_jar.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

To run a java jar file its file association should be properly configured. There is a free tool called [jarfix](http://johann.loefflmann.net/en/software/jarfix/index.html) to fix all jar file association problems. Run this file to fix all jar issues.

Comment: this is if you want to double click a .jar file in Windows Explorer to run it

Answer (score 0):

In the project properties dialog in NetBeans you need to set the Main Class - otherwise the generated .jar will not be executable.  Then, as already indicated, either double clicking on the .jar or the command java -jar  will start the program.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with running your jar, make sure you are trying to run your current version to get newest version in Netbeans: `GoTo Run Menu` --> `Clean and build`

Comment: How is this `answer` related to the `question` ?