# How to open NetBeans file?

Tags: file, netbeans

I am working for a project in netbeans. When i'll finish my project how can i execute my application (out of Netbeans)? I'm working for a little and simple guide of a game.

Comment: all the compiled files are inside the folder dist of your project folder

Comment: yes, but: fileName.CLASS, how can i open the .class files?

Comment: did you googled that question "how can i open the .class files" before?

Comment: yep but i there isn't anything

Comment: What language are you programming with? Is it Java, C, PHP...?

Comment: So you want to open a file with .class extension with netbeans right?

Comment: yeah but when i open my file i don't want to open netbenas too, for example "minecraft" :/, why minecraft run without run eclipse??

Comment: to execute your program just go to the terminal go to your project folder and type java <your .jar file>

Comment: But where i have to use that command?

Comment: Are you working at linux or windows?

Comment: i'm working at windows

Comment: try to click on top with the right mouse button and choose to open with the select java (don't know if this works).

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a .bat file with the following lines in it:

```
@ECHO OFF
set CLASSPATH=.
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;path/to/needed/jars/my.jar

%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -Xms128m -Xmx384m -Xnoclassgc ro.my.class.MyClass
```

Taken from this link :
[StackOverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938944/how-to-run-java-application-by-bat-file)

Comment: But if i open it with netbeans the program will open netbeans too?

Comment: Exactly. But what is the programming language which is being used for your project can you pls elaborate ?

Comment: im using java, do u want to see the program?

Comment: Ohk you want to run your code via NetBeans, try below:
To run the program:
Choose Run > Run Project.

Comment: He just wants to double click on the his program and run it

Comment: i want to run it out of netbens like a normal program

Comment: Ok, in that 1 suggestion is to create a batch file which indirectly runs a command like
1: Goes to the project directory 
2: java <programName>

Comment: He doesn't know how to use the terminal :( (please consider to start using linux, it's much more easy to work with java, c ...)

Comment: Try to right click on the file you want to run, and the choose run with (or something similar) and pick java. Does it works?

Comment: it say to me i have to install miscrosoft visual studio 2005 :S

Comment: lol. Do this them, go to the folder where you have the file you want to execute. Hold shift, right click the folder you want it opened on, and click "open command window here". Then type java <your file name with the extension> and press enter. (sorry but i don't use windows for 2 years, but I think this may work)

Comment: @user3721668 I have update my answer. Try doing that. It will serve your puprose hopefully.

Comment: BTW, learn try to learn a bit about how to use the command prompt where you have a tutorial for windows:http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr05/cos126/cmd-prompt.html

Comment: ok i'll try to do it, sry another time but i've only 15 years old, i never study IT at school...only next year, ty for ur time!

Answer (score 0):

To launch your java application use java.exe from the command line. See [How do I run a .jar executable java file from outside NetBeans IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176902/how-do-i-run-a-jar-executable-java-file-from-outside-netbeans-ide)